# How to serach multiselected comma separated stored ids using .net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, c#-3.0

During insert campaign, i am storing **multiselected**(checkbox List) events id stored using comma separated in **campaign table**. like 1,4,5,6

Now when i try to search campaign information based on these events ids, its not working proper . means when i try to search campaign by selecting event_id 1 ,it also search fields like 12,3,2  or 6,21,22 .

My search string is like following.

```
SELECT *
FROM `crm_campaign`
WHERE `event_ids` LIKE '%1,%'
OR `event_ids` LIKE '%,1,%'
OR `event_ids` LIKE '%,1%'
```

please give  me suggestion.

should i change data structure for multiselect fields ?

Now i am inserting event_ids like '1','4','5' 
Is it right approch ? 
If Yes then then how to use search string in asp.net because these escape character gives me problem for  mysqlcommand paramter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating commas to the start and end of `event_ids` in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `crm_campaign`
WHERE concat(',', `event_ids`, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Due to the nature of the table design, it will be slow if your table contains many rows.
If this becomes an issue, move the event ids into a separate related table.

Comment: Please try again now, I have changed to MySql syntax

Comment: @UdaySatardekar, if this answer worked for you, please click the check-mark to the left of this answer to let others know that it worked and so that Will receives credit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use List or an array. If you have a comma separated string, using split function to get array of values and query against the array.

Comment: Thanks.. BuT give me example please.because i m new in programming